# What is the working mechanism of the atypical antipsychotic Olanzapine?

Tags: pain, medication

I'm a 3th year medicine student and I'm working on a paper including the possible analgesic effects of Olanzapine on complex regional pain syndrome (CRPS). The mechanism of pain perception in CRPS is due to central sensitization and sympathetic activated pain. The nociceptive receptors that are responsible for allodynia are located in the spinal column (dorsal horn) and periphery. Now knowing that olanzapine (Zyprexa) is an agonist of alpha-2-adrenergic receptors, does that also include adrenergic receptors in the dorsal horn and periphery (as example  the limbs)? Or does olanzapine only have effect in the brain?

Comment: Although this isn't off topic here, I think you're more likely to get answers in Psychology & Neuroscience, so I'm migrating it there.

Comment: This is how I'm reading your question: are there alpha 2 receptors in the PNS?

Comment: You're likely done with your paper, but I'm going to leave a comment. Your question is complex, so I hope I can provide a useful comment. I have CRPS with my main pain being in my right leg and foot. I see a pain management doctor every month to assess my status and get my meds. I also have bipolar I disorder and Zyprexa is one of my medications for that. I have not noticed any change in feeling with my pain since beginning Zyprexa. It was not helpful for my limb pain. This is purely anecdotal, I know, but it's one person's experience :)